# Does org have any "inverse-tangle" operations e.g. for collaborating with non-org users?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming

I would like to write my own notes/tests/code in org and then use `org-bable-tangle` to produce source files.  However, all of these files are subject to version control and hence subject to change from outside my org environment.

I would like to be able to have a number of `src` blocks and then tangle to a bunch of different files, each of which would be commit to version control.  But at the same time, be able to "untangle" each of these files back into my org file after pulling any changes from version control.

Is there any straightforward way of doing this?  I am now considering playing with `insert-file-contents`

Comment: Could you provide a little example of what you are asking to do? It sounds like you have code blocks in one or more org files and you want the file or files generated from the tangle of these blocks to disassemble into the original blocks with changes in the org files.

Comment: Essentially the workflow would be like this:  (1) write some literate code in org.  (2) tangle that code to one or more files.  (3) git commit those files.  (4) have lunch (5) git pull my colleague's changes.  (6) "inverse-tangle" those changes back into code blocks in my org file.  (7) goto (1).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's `org-babel-detangle`.

> org-babel-detangle is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `ob-tangle.el`.
>
> `(org-babel-detangle &optional SOURCE-CODE-FILE)`
>
> Propagate changes in source file back original to Org file. This
>   requires that code blocks were tangled with link comments which enable
>   the original code blocks to be found.

You need to set the `comments` header argument to `link` to make it work, for example,

```
#+begin_src ruby :tangle hello.rb :comments link
  puts 'hello'
#+end_src
```

then use `M-x org-babel-tangle` to export the code block, a new file named `hello.rb` will be created, it should have similar contents like the following

```
~ $ cat hello.rb
# [[file:~/foo.org][No heading:1]]
puts 'hello'
# No heading:1 ends here
~ $
```

Finally, open `hello.rb` in Emacs, change `hello` to `hello world`, and run `M-x org-babel-detangle` in `hello.rb`'s buffer. The org file will be updated

```
#+begin_src ruby :tangle hello.rb :comments link
  puts 'hello world'
#+end_src
```

Comment: Could you be more precise (or give an example) on how to use this org-babel-detangle function. I tried with your ruby code to use M x org-babel-detangle after tangling to hello.rb and modifying lightly the code but I have an error "org-babel-detangle: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil".

Comment: @Lgen I've updated my answer. And don't forget to read `org-babel-detangle`'s docstring to understand the purpose and the usage.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I had not understood the assumption that the source code had to be edited within emacs to allow reverse tangling (I was using another text editor to modify the source code). It works as expected now.

Comment: This is nice feature, but isn't quite what I was hoping to find.  I can't really commit the #[[...]] comments since they don't mean anything except to myself.  Is it possible to annotate a source block to detangle from an entire file without requiring the link comment?  Essentially just `insert-file-contents` ?

Answer (score 8):

There is also [org-tanglesync](https://github.com/mtekman/org-tanglesync.el), which has a much simpler method of syncing than `org-babel-detangle`

Essentially if a block is tangled to an external file, then every time that block is edited the external file is checked also, and if a diff is detected, the user is prompted to either reject or pull the external changes into the org src block.

This also has functions to automatically process all tangled blocks in a buffer. I hope it helps.

Comment: FYI for anyone who's planning to try this out, this doesn't to support tangling multiple source blocks to a single file: https://gitlab.com/mtekman/org-tanglesync.el/-/issues/13